Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, read - TypeOrmModule
When runing pnpm run start:dev
[14:35:56] File change detected. Starting incremental compilation...
[14:35:56] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, read
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1397:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/my-path/my-app/node_modules/.pnpm/typeorm@0.3.20_ts-node@10.9.2/src/driver/sqlite/SqliteDriver.ts:1:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)

This error occurs only when importing TypeOrmModule in app.module.ts.
I double-checked the import statements to ensure that i'm importing TypeOrmModule from @nestjs/typeorm and not from a different module that might be referencing SQLite. I also cleared Node Modules and restarted the application after deleting and reinstalling node modules.
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot(), DatabaseModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    DatabaseService,
    ClassTransformInterceptor.Provider,
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: ClassSerializerInterceptor,
    },
  ],
  exports: [ConfigModule],
})
export class AppModule {}```


See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , This is specific to your project and needs to be debugged. This obviously doesn't happen to anyone who uses nestjs+typeorm. Could be specific to pnpm
